# connecting mysql into javafx application

Tags: java, mysql, database, authentication, javafx

I'm trying to check the login but I keep getting error.

First the check function in different class:

```
public class JavaDBConnection{

public boolean auth(String user, String pass) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        boolean login;
        Connection conn =null;
        String dbuser = "root";
        String dbpassw = "0557724289";
        String databasename = "java_cinemaTickets";
        String url = "jdbc:Mysql@127.0.0.1:3306/java_cinemaTickets";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,dbuser,dbpassw);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();

       PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT `customer_name`, `customer_password` FROM `customer` WHERE `customer_name` = ? AND `customer_password` = ?");

       ps.setString(1, user);
       ps.setString(2, pass);

       ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
        if(result.next()){
             login = true;
    } 
        else{login = false;}

        return login;

}


   }
```

Then in the other class:

```
public class Java_CinemaTicket extends Application {

JavaDBConnection db = new JavaDBConnection();


public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws FileNotFoundException {


    // Login Stage Start

    VBox login_pane = new VBox(15);
    login_pane.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
    GridPane login_gridPane = new GridPane();
    login_gridPane.setHgap(5);
    login_gridPane.setVgap(5);


    TextField user_name = new TextField();
    PasswordField user_password = new PasswordField();
```

later on the class:

```
login_button.setOnAction(e->{
     String userNamestring = user_name.getText();
     String userstring = user_password.getText();
    if(customer_radioButton.isSelected()==true){
         try {
             if(db.auth(userNamestring, userstring) == true){
                 primaryStage.setTitle("Customer GUI");
                 primaryStage.setScene(customer);
                 primaryStage.show();
             }} catch (SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(Java_CinemaTicket.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(Java_CinemaTicket.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }
  }
```

And the output error:

```
 Dec 02, 2016 1:47:56 AM java_cinematicket.Java_CinemaTicket lambda$start$3
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for      jdbc:Mysql@127.0.0.1:3306/java_cinemaTickets
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at     java_cinematicket.JavaMongoDBConnection.auth(JavaMongoDBConnection.java:27)
at     java_cinematicket.Java_CinemaTicket.lambda$start$3(Java_CinemaTicket.java:453)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
```

Note in the database there is customer table:

[image]
This is my problem. Any suggestion how to fix it.

Comment: If one of the answers fixed your problem, please make it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying there is no suitable driver.
Try changing your jdbc url to

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/java_cinemaTickets";
```

Answer (score 0):

Connection string should be:

```
"jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/java_cinemaTickets"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the jar file to your project resources?

http://oopbook.com/java-classpath-2/classpath-in-netbeans/